# Problems creating a vertically aligned gallery in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to vertically aligned 10 images, 5 on top and 5 on the bottom to look something like this:

[image]

The problem is that I just can't do it and it's driving me insane. Here is the HTML code for the gallery:

```
    <div class ="gallery">
<div class="img_cont">
    <div class="set1">
                <ul>
                    <div class ="item"><li><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img1.jpg"  width="200" height="200"    alt="Hole 1"></li></div>    
                    <div class ="item"><li><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img2.jpg"  width="200" height="200"    alt="Hole 2"></li></div>
                    <div class ="item"><li><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img3.jpg"  width="200" height="200"    alt="Hole 3"></li></div>
                    <div class ="item"><li><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img4.jpg"  width="200" height="200"    alt="Hole 4"></li></div>
                    <div class ="item"><li><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img5.jpg"  width="200" height="200"    alt="Hole 5"></li></div>                        
                </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="img_cont">
    <div class="set">
                <ul>
                    <div class ="item"><li><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img6.jpg"  width="200" height="200"    alt="Hole 6"></li></div>    
                    <div class ="item"><li><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img7.jpg"  width="200" height="200"    alt="Hole 7"></li></div>
                    <div class ="item"><li><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img8.jpg"  width="200" height="200"    alt="Hole 8"></li></div>
                    <div class ="item"><li><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img9.jpg"  width="200" height="200"    alt="Hole 9"></li></div>
                    <div class ="item"><li><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img10.jpg"  width="200" height="200"   alt="Hole 10"></li></div>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and Here's the CSS code I use for the specific gallery:

```
    .gallery li:hover{
    transform:scale(1.2,1.2);


}


.gallery {

position: relative;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;


}
.img_cont{

padding-top: 20%; /* forces 1:1 aspect ratio */


}



.item{

position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
vertical-align:center;
text-align:center; /* Align center inline elements */
font: 0/0 a;
}
```

My problem is that images are stuck in the center on top of each other and I need them as in the picture. Can you please give me an advice and tell me what I am doing wrong, thanks in advance!

Comment: remove item class of all div's and see the diff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out - https://jsfiddle.net/8mx25314/
Hope this helps.

Updated css is

```
 .gallery li:hover{
    transform:scale(1.2,1.2);
}

.gallery {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
}
.img_cont{
padding-top: 20%; /* forces 1:1 aspect ratio */
}
.item{
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
vertical-align:center;
text-align:center; /* Align center inline elements */
font: 0/0 a;
width: 17%;
padding-left:2.5%;
}
.item img{
    width: 100%!important;
    height: auto;
}
ul{
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of issues with your HTML and CSS that are messing up your intent:

- No closing of `img` or `a` tags
- Unnecessary use of `ul`
- `div` tags as children of `ul`
- all `.item` divs being absolutely positioned to the same place

I have simplified your code a lot to show two rows of aligned images without the `ul` and more understandable styles:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lot8r08p/

(I made the images quite a bit smaller to fit in the jsfiddle window)

HTML:

```
<div class ="gallery">
    <div class="img_cont">
        <div class="set1">
            <div class ="item"><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img1.jpg" alt="Hole 1" /></a></div>    
            <div class ="item"><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img2.jpg" alt="Hole 2"/></a></div>
            <div class ="item"><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img3.jpg" alt="Hole 3"/></a></div>
            <div class ="item"><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img4.jpg" alt="Hole 4"/></a></div>
            <div class ="item"><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img5.jpg" alt="Hole 5"/></a></div>                             </div>
    </div>

    <div class="img_cont">
        <div class="set">
            <div class ="item"><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img6.jpg" alt="Hole 6"/></a></div>    
            <div class ="item"><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img7.jpg" alt="Hole 7"/></a></div>
            <div class ="item"><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img8.jpg" alt="Hole 8"/></a></div>
            <div class ="item"><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img9.jpg" alt="Hole 9"/></a></div>
            <div class ="item"><a href="#"><img src ="/public/images/img10.jpg" alt="Hole 10"/></a></div>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.gallery .img_cont {
    text-align: center;
}

.item{
    display: inline-block;
}

.item img {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
```